# How to delete a photo posted by an App in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have created an app to post a photo in Facebook. I want to delete those photos posted by my app. I have read the documentation and found that Facebook allows Apps to delete the photos posted by them. [Click Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos) This link gives the answer for my question.

`You can delete photos for a user posted from your app by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to PROFILE_ID/photos with the user access token or app access_token.`

But how to issue a HTTP delete request. Don't we need the photo id for deleting the photo?
I have tried to send a `HTTP DELETE REQUEST` as mentioned above using `PHP SDK.` But I got an error like this

`Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported delete request.`

This is how I send the request

`$response = $facebook->api('/me/photos/','delete',array("photoid" => "$photoid"));`

Please help

Comment: In the code you've given, you haven't shown that you are setting the correct access token... are you using the `setAccessToken()` method?

Comment: Yes I am using. I don't know how to give the photo id.

Comment: Have you tried with simply `id`?

Comment: Just now Have edited the code. Mentioned 'id' instead of 'photoid'
This is the error

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid token: "me". An ID has already been specified.

Comment: Ok.. what if you try instead of `/me/photos`, to just give `/PHOTO_ID` and then issue the delete request with out any extra parameters?

Comment: This is the error
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:

Comment: Ok - one final attempt :) Try issuing a delete (with no other parameters) to `/USERID_PHOTOID`. Thats the user's ID and then underscore then the photo's ID.

Comment: It worked thanks. I just gave the photo id with delete request, it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Awesome :) Let me just add that as an answer so it might help people in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to delete a photo that was created by the application, you have to make a `DELETE` request to a url like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID
```

I'm not sure why the documentation states otherwise (might be worth a bug report).

So in the PHP SDK, it would look something like this:

```
$facebook->setAccessToken( YOUR_APP_TOKEN );
$response = $facebook->api( '/PHOTO_ID', 'delete' );
```